# How to check data types holding numeric values with decimal is empty

Tags: java, android

I want to check if `tempDouble` is empty,. I am using `if (!tempDouble.isNaN())`, Is this the correct way to doing it ?

```
public Double tempDouble, tempDouble2;
buttonDec.setOnClickListener(
    new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                if ( output.getText().length() <= 0 ) {

                }
                else {
                    i = Integer.parseInt(output.getText().toString());
                    output.setText(i + ".");

                    if ( !tempDouble.isNaN() ) {
                    // check if tempDouble is empty
                        //tempDouble = Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());
                    }
                    else
                        tempDouble2=Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());                        
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Where is `tempDouble` actually defined, and could you do a `null` check instead?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post the stack trace here please?

Comment: You're not getting the result... what result are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(tempDouble == null){ // tempDouble is null
    // Do stuff
else { // tempDouble is not null
    tempDouble2=Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());
}
```

If you only want to do stuff to tempDouble when it isn't null, you can reduce these statments to:

```
if(tempDouble != null){
    tempDouble2=Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());  
}
```

I hope this helps Kushal!